# iTextSharp image stretching not proportional

Tags: wpf, itext

I am using Telerik `RadRadialGauge` and I need to export it to pdf like a picture.
On my GUI the control looks normal

[image]

When I try to export it to pdf it is resized not proportionally.
[image]

All other elements look good.

```
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(pdfFile, FileMode.Create));
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms).SetFullCompression();
                document.Open();

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(imageFile1, FileMode.Open);
                var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(fs);
                image.ScalePercent(80);
              //   image.ScaleToFit(document.PageSize.Width , document.PageSize.Height);
              //   image.ScaleAbsolute(document.PageSize.Width , document.PageSize.Height));
                document.Add(image);
                }
```

Here the code to save all the data from GUI as png file.

```
     private void SaveAsPng(RenderTargetBitmap src, string targetFile)
    {
        try
        {
            PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src));

            using (var stm = File.Create(targetFile))
            {
                encoder.Save(stm);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ...            }
    }
```

Comment: Please share the image in question.

Comment: I added 2 images.Image from GUI and image when I try to export

Comment: Is the first image identical to the one you have at `imageFile1`?

Comment: The first image identical the image that you can see on the GUI(user control). <telerik:RadRadialGauge

Comment: I think the problem when I save data from GUI to png before converting to pdf because I can see png image resized.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, as I could not reproduce the issue with the original image you posted...